# BoxCutter Hard Ops sort issue

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel, vertex-groups

so i have a bit of don't know why it's not working situation, adding a vertex group into a bevel and changing the sorting options on both Boxcutter and Hardops to ignore the Vgroups Bevels ( it does not matter if you toggle it or not), nothing happens and the sorting will not work anymore, it seems is still working for other modifiers but not for the bevel in question, this is a bit detailed screenshot of what's happening on my blender ( https://ibb.co/7SccvZ4 ), any suggestions? :(

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Okey thank you very much 